How to use Rmarkdown with natbib citation package?
I am trying to write a PDF article in Rmarkdown, and want to include a scientific bibliography using the latex natbib citation package.
Unfortunately, I get an error message.
This is a minimum example that contains the most important details of the Rmarkdown document:
---
output: 
  pdf_document:
     citation_package: natbib
bibliography: test_library.bib
---

@GoelThakor2008

The file test_library.bib contains just one article, for brevity:
@article{GoelThakor2008, 
year = {2008}, 
title = {{Overconfidence, CEO selection, and corporate governance}}, 
author = {Goel, Anand M and Thakor, Anjan V}, 
journal = {Journal of Finance}, 
pages = {2737 -- 2784}, 
volume = {63},  
month = {00}
}

After compiling, or "knitting", the Rmarkdown file into a PDF file using Rstudio, I get a long error message, part of which is this:
Warning: Package natbib Warning: Citation `GoelThakor2008' on page 1 undefined on input
Warning: Package natbib Warning: There were undefined citations.
Interestingly, if I comment-out the line citation_package: natbib then it works like a charm.

Can you check if markdown and your tex distribution are up to date? Your example works fine for me. Can you also show your .blg and .log files?

Thanks for the quick answer! I have downloaded the entire MacTeX distribution this morning. Also, in Rstudio, I have clicked on Tools -> Check for package updates, so I would think that everything is up to date. Let me upload my .log file.

Please add the file as text. And please also show the .blg file

I'm sorry, I was looking for the .blg file but I couldn't find it. But let me upload my .log file as text as you asked for. (I am not allowed to upload the entire log file, just the first few lines.)

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (TeX Live 2024) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2024.5.14)  14 MAY 2024 14:19
entering extended mode
restricted \write18 enabled.
%&-line parsing enabled.
**article.tex
(./article.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-02-20>
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)

After a lot of debugging, I figured out the answer: The filename test_library.bib has an underscore "_" that latex natbib cannot handle.
Once I renamed the file to testlibrary.bib the file compiled correctly.
